# name to twitter user name using R

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping, rtweet

I have a list of local election candidates and I would like to find out

(i)  if these individuals have a twitter account 
(ii) if so what are their screen names/ user names.

**search_users** seemed to be the best option but it does not do a good job. Here is an example:

```
y1 <- search_users(q="suleyman kilinc", n=5, parse=TRUE)
```

This gives me a list of 5 users and non of them is the one that I am looking for. This is often the case. But when I do the same search on Google with the key words "suleyman+kilinc+twitter", the first option that Google offers is what I exactly need. This is true for 95% of the random names that I manually searched. Is there a good way to automatize the name to user name search through R or a better option than search_users function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If not through the Twitter API, where do you intend to be searching? With out that, this is pretty vague.

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to do it in general is an automated search in twitter through a keyword but I want the most popular result to show up first (like in google) not in some random order as search_users function does.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting question. the `q` parameter accepts a string as indicated above. When you pass a word with space as a value of `q` then you are instructing the function to search for "suleyman" & "kilinc" hence "suleyman kilinc" is the same as "suleyman AND kilinc". The REST API for twitter in this case will return any user with both  "suleyman" and "kilinc"  irregardless of the order.